How to perform SIM card geolocation using RADIUS data for 2G, 3G, and 4G?
I am trying to perform geolocation of a SIM card using cell tower data provided by the RADIUS protocol. My goal is to correctly identify the cell's (or SIM card's) location for 2G, 3G, and 4G technologies.
I have a reference cell tower with the following data:
3GPP: 0x0127f45075e879aa
Tecnologia: UTRA
Operadora: Claro
Endereço informado: R JOSIVALDO GOMES S/N ESQUINA COM A RUA JOÃO LEÃO FERNANDES
Additionally, the RADIUS data provides the following information:
{ "mobileCountryCode": 724, "mobileNetworkCode": 5, "locationAreaCode": 30184, "cellId": 30275 }
I am using the Google Geolocation API to try to determine the location. Here is an example of what I’ve attempted:
`curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MINHA_API_KEY' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "radioType": "WCDMA",
    "considerIp": false,
    "homeMobileCountryCode": 724,
    "homeMobileNetworkCode": 5,
    "cellTowers": [
        {
            "mobileCountryCode": 724,
            "mobileNetworkCode": 5,
            "locationAreaCode": 30184,
            "cellId": 30275
        }
    ]
}'`

However, I did not get a valid response from the API. Additionally, when checking the cell tower data on the operator's website, the address associated with this cell does not seem to match.
My questions:
How can I interpret and convert 3GPP User Location Info data (such as 3GPP: 0x0127f45075e879aa) into usable information for geolocation?
Am I correctly setting up the parameters for the Google API? Is there anything missing or incorrect for 2G, 3G, or 4G technologies?
Is there a better approach to identify the cell's location or verify the data returned by the API?
I would appreciate any guidance or practical examples to help solve this issue. Thank you!
